# How do you make the slider track transparent using CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the slider track transparent for a range input but not the thumb. What does the CSS for this look like?

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);">
  <input type="range" />
</div>
```

Comment: Not much info out there on how to do this. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a reliable cross-browser way to do this. Since your body's background is black, you can set the background of the input to black as well in these examples.

In Firefox, you can use the non-standard `::-moz-range-track` pseudo-element:

```css
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    background: transparent;
}

input[type=range] {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: black;">
    <input type="range">
</div>
```

In Chrome-based browsers like Chrome, Opera, Brave, and Edge (and, currently, Firefox while they support -webkit- vendor prefixes), you simply hide the input via `-webkit-appearance`:

```css
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: black">
    <input type="range">
</div>
```

In IE11 and Edge, sliders work as a fillable meter, so you have to use two styles to hide the track itself *and* the filled amount: `::-ms-track` and `::-ms-fill-lower`:

```css
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

IE11 does not like to play well with black backgrounds, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195140/discussion-between-tylerh-and-sepehr-sobhani).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
input[type=range] {
   background: #00000000;
}
```

should solve it

Comment: This doesn't do anything. By the way, hex values for colors are typically 6 characters (hence the name, "hex"). Are you thinking of Android aRGB values?

Comment: @TylerH You can add to numbers after the hex color code to do opacity